# Creating a basic ab + a'c circuit on a breadboard, how are the inputs placed?

Tags: digital-logic, breadboard, logic-gates

I am supposed to design my first circuit on a breadboard and the output will be defined by the logical formula:
ab + a'c

The problem is I don't understand how are the inputs placed, a b c as inputs are three connections to the main power souce? or what?

I tried to test a simpler circuit:
a+b

[image: r]

But my simulation doesn't light the led. Can someone tell me why is this wrong?

Comment: I guess the idea is to create a practical circuit because you've mentioned a breadboard? In that case I guess this is some sort of homework so did they cover actual logic gates like maybe the 7400 series?

Comment: I actually designed the circuit using 1 or, not, and gates each. But I'm my circuit has 3 inputs... the question is is each one a serial ramification of the power entrance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, as you commented: "I actually designed the circuit using 1 or, not, and gates each.", then your lineup is wrong and should be:\$\ \$ two ANDs, one NOT, and one OR, and your logic should look like this:

[image]

I don't know what you're trying to imply with your breadboard example, but in the real world it should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: This looks a bit more like it. Out of interest what did you use to draw the lower diagram?

Comment: @PeterJ: AutoCAD 14.

Answer (score 1):

One way to supply inputs is to use dip switches. Connect a 10k pullup to VCC for each of the inputs. Connect a dip switch to each input. The other side of the dip switch would be connected to ground. So when the switch is open, the 10k pullup causes the input to be high. When the switch is closed, the input will be shorted to GND, so the input will be low. This is a pretty standard way to do this, but not the only way.

If you want, you can directly connect the inputs to VCC or GND with a wire. Or you can connect them to VCC for high or GND for low with a resistor in series. If it is CMOS logic, the resistor can be almost any value from 0 to 100k with no worries.

Comment: Can you check my simulation? I edited the main post.